# Bluetooth keyboard won't re-pair to my Galaxy Note 10.1

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I bought a Bluetooth keyboard and it worked beautifully for 2 days. I then unpaired it to use on my friend's tablet and it worked amazingly well on hers as well. When I went to re-pair the keyboard to my Note 10.1 it shows up in the Bluetooth devices list, but the box to type in the code will not come up and there is no settings cog next to the name like there should be. So the keyboard has become useless as I can not for the life of me find a way to re-pair and connect it to my tablet. I am running android 4.1.2. Please help as I need this to work for school. I purchased this to take notes in class.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your bluetooth radar and then trying to reconnect? Reboot your device if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so so stupid I tried everything from bluetooth apps, turning bluetoooth on and off, holding the name of the keyboard to see if I could get a box to pop up even scanned it for virus. In doing all that I never thought to restart the tablet lol. I can build and program computers, but can't think of restart tablet lol. Anyway thank you again.

Comment: @John Well done! Now please add that as an answer, so other users can see the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is typical of some sort of internal error, you could try restating your bluetooth service. If this doesn't work a quick reboot is likely to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Samsung Rep at my local Best Buy figured this out.

1- goto **Settings/Applications/Applications Manager**

2- select **BLE Scanner**, then click on **CLEAR DATA**

3- select **Bluetooth Pair**, then click on **CLEAR DATA**

4- restart the tablet